# How to declare and use map/dictionary in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

is it possible something like this is node.js ?

```
var LANGUAGE = {
    LANG1: 'Language 1',
    LANG2 'Language 2'
}

var TARGET = {
    TARG1: { LANG1: 'target 1 in lang 1', LANG2: 'target 1 in lang 2' },
    TARG2: { LANG1: 'target 2 in lang 1', LANG2: 'target 2 in lang 2' }
}

var ACTION = {
    ACT1: { LANG1: 'action 1 in lang 1', LANG2: 'action 1 in lang 2' },
    ACT2: { LANG1: 'action 2 in lang 1', LANG2: 'action 2 in lang 2' }  
}


var currentLanguage = LANGUAGE.LANG1;
var currentTarget = TARGET.TARG2;
var currentAction = ACTION.ACT1;

var message = 'You have successfully performed ' + currentAction[currentLanguage] + ' on ' + currentTarget[currentLanguage];

console.log(message);
```

I'm not sure that in the source above there is any relation between **LANGUAGE.LANG1** and **TARG1: { LANG1**:   etc...

**======== updated with the result after running this in VSCode =======**

```
You have successfully performed undefined on undefined
```

Comment: Try saving this in a file and running it with `node`.  I assure you that `node` knows Javascript better than any human on this site.  If you run into issues that you have trouble understanding, including the errors you're unclear about would turn this into a great question.

Comment: There is nothing as _dictionary_ in NodeJS. You may want to read about [working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) and the [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) API.

Comment: @ctt I've updated the post. There is no errors but unfortunately there are undefined values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, yes. Your problem is that the values in your LANGUAGE object need to be the keys in the other objects, so...

```
var LANGUAGE = {
    LANG1: 'LANG1',
    LANG2: 'LANG1'
}
```

(You're also missing the second colon in the code you posted.)

Using the above prints...

> You have successfully performed action 1 in lang 1 on target 2 in lang 1

Answer (score 2):

You should read more about javascript dot and bracket notation.
In your case `currentAction[currentLanguage]` will be `currentAction['Language 1']` and there is no value with key `'Language 1'` in the `currentAction` object (which equals to `{ LANG1: 'action 1 in lang 1', LANG2: 'action 1 in lang 2' }`)
`currentAction['LANG1']` or `currentAction.LANG1` will return the value you want.

ES6 has the dynamic key syntax, where you can use a variable for the key in object literal
`{ [LANGUAGE.LANG1]: 'some value'}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to 31piy,

I've found a way it works. Maybe it's not the best one.

```
var LANGUAGE = {
    LANG1: 'Language 1',
    LANG2: 'Language 2'
}

var TARGET = {
    TARG1: new Map(),
    TARG2: new Map() 
}

var ACTION = {
    ACT1: new Map(),
    ACT2: new Map() 
}

TARGET.TARG1.set(LANGUAGE.LANG1, 'target 1 in lang 1');
TARGET.TARG1.set(LANGUAGE.LANG2, 'target 1 in lang 2');
TARGET.TARG2.set(LANGUAGE.LANG1, 'target 2 in lang 1');
TARGET.TARG2.set(LANGUAGE.LANG2, 'target 2 in lang 2');

ACTION.ACT1.set(LANGUAGE.LANG1, 'action 1 in lang 1');
ACTION.ACT1.set(LANGUAGE.LANG2, 'action 1 in lang 2');
ACTION.ACT2.set(LANGUAGE.LANG1, 'action 2 in lang 1');
ACTION.ACT2.set(LANGUAGE.LANG2, 'action 2 in lang 2');

var currentLanguage = LANGUAGE.LANG1;
var currentTarget = TARGET.TARG2;
var currentAction = ACTION.ACT1;

var message = 'You have successfully performed ' + currentAction.get(currentLanguage) + ' on ' + currentTarget.get(currentLanguage);

console.log(message);
```

And the result is as expected :)

```
You have successfully performed action 1 in lang 1 on target 2 in lang 1
```